# Mpi4py exec starts the process but doesnt do anithing after

Tags: mpi4py

im trying to peralel the Betweenness centrality and to test it i am trying to launch the program with the line
`mpiexec -n 7 python3 ProjectMain.py`
The code starts without erorrs but doesnt compleate anything, not even the first print test
the problem is somewhere in my def betweenness_centrality function yet i cant find a solution

```
from mpi4py import MPI
import time
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import time
import betweenparalel as bpl
from heapq import heappush, heappop
from itertools import count
import random

print("test")

name = MPI.Get_processor_name()
comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()
size = comm.Get_size()
print(rank)

def betweenness_centrality(G, k=None, normalized=True, weight=None,
                           endpoints=False,
                           seed=None):
    if rank == 0:
        betweenness = dict.fromkeys(G, 0.0)  # b[v]=0 for v in G
        if k is None:
            nodes = G
        else:
            random.seed(seed)
            nodes = random.sample(G.nodes(), k)
        for s in nodes:
            comm.send(s, dest=s, tag=0)
            print("sent s = ", s)
    if rank != 0:
        betweenness = None
        betweenness = comm.bcast(betweenness, root=0)
        s = comm.recv(source=0, tag=0)
    if rank == 1:
        if weight is None:  # use BFS
            S, P, sigma = bpl._single_source_shortest_path_basic(G, s)
        if endpoints:
            betweenness1 = bpl._accumulate_endpoints(betweenness, S, P, sigma, s)
        else:
            betweenness1 = bpl._accumulate_basic(betweenness, S, P, sigma, s)
        comm.send(betweenness1, dest=2, tag=1)
        print("1 done")
    if rank == 2:
        if weight is None:  # use BFS
            S, P, sigma = bpl._single_source_shortest_path_basic(G, s)
        if endpoints:
            betweenness2 = bpl._accumulate_endpoints(betweenness, S, P, sigma, s)
        else:
            betweenness2 = bpl._accumulate_basic(betweenness, S, P, sigma, s)
        betweenness1 = comm.recv( source=1, tag=1)
        if endpoints:
            betweenness2 = bpl._accumulate_endpoints(betweenness1, S, P, sigma, s)
        else:
            betweenness2 = bpl._accumulate_basic(betweenness1, S, P, sigma, s)
        comm.send(betweenness2, dest=4, tag=2)
        print("2 done")
    if rank == 3:
        if weight is None:  # use BFS
            S, P, sigma = bpl._single_source_shortest_path_basic(G, s)
        if endpoints:
            betweenness3 = bpl._accumulate_endpoints(betweenness, S, P, sigma, s)
        else:
            betweenness3 = bpl._accumulate_basic(betweenness, S, P, sigma, s)
        comm.send(betweenness3, dest=4, tag=3)
        print("3 done")
    if rank == 4:
        if weight is None:  # use BFS
            S, P, sigma = bpl._single_source_shortest_path_basic(G, s)
        if endpoints:
            betweenness4 = bpl._accumulate_endpoints(betweenness, S, P, sigma, s)
        else:
            betweenness4 = bpl._accumulate_basic(betweenness, S, P, sigma, s)
        betweenness3 = comm.recv( source=3, tag=3)
        if endpoints:
            betweenness4 = bpl._accumulate_endpoints(betweenness3, S, P, sigma, s)
        else:
            betweenness4 = bpl._accumulate_basic(betweenness3, S, P, sigma, s)
        betweenness2 = comm.recv( source=2, tag=2)
        if endpoints:
            betweenness4 = bpl._accumulate_endpoints(betweenness2, S, P, sigma, s)
        else:
            betweenness4 = bpl._accumulate_basic(betweenness2, S, P, sigma, s)
        comm.send(betweenness4, dest=6, tag=4)
        print("4 done")
    if rank == 5:
        if weight is None:  # use BFS
            S, P, sigma = bpl._single_source_shortest_path_basic(G, s)
        if endpoints:
            betweenness5 = bpl._accumulate_endpoints(betweenness, S, P, sigma, s)
        else:
            betweenness5 = bpl._accumulate_basic(betweenness, S, P, sigma, s)
        comm.send(betweenness5, dest=6, tag=5)
        print("5 done")
    if rank == 6:
        if weight is None:  # use BFS
            S, P, sigma = bpl._single_source_shortest_path_basic(G, s)
        if endpoints:
            betweenness6 = bpl._accumulate_endpoints(betweenness, S, P, sigma, s)
        else:
            betweenness6 = bpl._accumulate_basic(betweenness, S, P, sigma, s)
        betweenness5 = comm.recv( source=5, tag=5)
        if endpoints:
            betweenness6 = bpl._accumulate_endpoints(betweenness5, S, P, sigma, s)
        else:
            betweenness6 = bpl._accumulate_basic(betweenness5, S, P, sigma, s)
        betweenness4 = comm.recv( source=4, tag=4)
        if endpoints:
            betweenness6 = bpl._accumulate_endpoints(betweenness4, S, P, sigma, s)
        else:
            betweenness6 = bpl._accumulate_basic(betweenness4, S, P, sigma, s)
        comm.send(betweenness6, dest=0, tag=6)
        print("6 done")
    if rank == 0:
        betweenness = comm.recv( source=6, tag=6)
        # rescaling
        betweenness = bpl._rescale(betweenness, len(G),
                                normalized=normalized,
                                directed=G.is_directed(),
                                k=k)
        print("0 done")
    return betweenness

if rank != 0:
    G = None

if rank == 0:
    G = nx.Graph()

    G.add_node(1)
    G.add_node(2)
    G.add_node(3)
    G.add_node(4)
    G.add_node(5)
    G.add_node(6)
    print("nodes set")

    G.add_edge(1, 2)
    G.add_edge(2, 3)
    G.add_edge(1, 3)
    G.add_edge(3, 4)
    G.add_edge(4, 5)
    G.add_edge(4, 6)
    G.add_edge(5, 6)
    print("edges set")

    stimeA =time.time()
    betweeness_dictA = bpl.betweenness_centrality(G)
    print(betweeness_dictA)
    etimeA =time.time()
    print("Time of normal Betweenness centralization --- %s seconds ---" % (etimeA - stimeA))

G = comm.bcast(G, root=0)

stimeB =time.time()
betweeness_dict = betweenness_centrality(G)
etimeB =time.time()
if rank == 0:
    print(betweeness_dict)
    print("Time of paralel Betweenness centralization --- %s seconds ---" % (etimeB - stimeB))
```

Any ideas?

i have tested the code without the function and it works normally.
the function itself should not have problems, so i bealive it has something to do with the different ranks not working in uniso, instead they seem to work in a random order.

Answer (score 0):

Your code may be running just fine.  In order to get statements to print when running with `mpiexec` you should specify `flush=True` in your print statements.

Try adding

`print('your message', flush=True)`

To your statements and see if your code is working.